# Swap values of x and y

Tags: c++

How can I change the values of x and y in this code?

When I try to do it by `x=y, y=x;` it changes it to the same numbers.

How can I do this?

How can I do this for 3 values like (`x` `y` `z`)?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x=4;
    int y=6;
    cout<<x<<y;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried this code before but it isn't working the way I want it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x=4;
    int y=6;
    x=y,y=x;
    cout<<x<<y;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The word is "swap". You get pretty good google results for that.

Comment: The C++ standard library comes with many nice [algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) and [utility](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility) functions.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you first set `x`'s value and then copy that value into `y`. There is a standard library function called `std::swap`, which should do the job.

You can see an exapmle of it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).

`std::swap` is defined in the header `<algorithm>` before C++11 and in `<utility>` since C++11. So make sure you `#include` the correct header.

The benefit of using `std::swap` in C++11 as opposed to having a third temporary variable that you copy the value into, is that `std::swap` uses `std::move` and thereby creates no additional copies.

---

For three numbers you'll have to make your own implementation like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int x{5}, y{3}, z{2};

    int temp{std::move(x)};
    x = std::move(y);
    y = std::move(z);
    z = std::move(temp);

    std::cout << x << ' ' << y << ' ' << z << '\n';

    return 0;

}
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/uLIWx5)

Answer (score 2):

For 2 variables, you should use `std::swap`, for more variables, you may use `std::tuple`:

```
std::tie(x, y, z) = std::make_tuple(y, z, x);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/r30K3n)

Comment: Also, I believe `std::tie(x, y, z) = { y, z, x };` is sufficient

Comment: @M.M: Demo fixed.

Comment: @M.M: `std::tie(x, y, z) = { y, z, x };` would be `std::tie(x, y, z) = std::tie(y, z, x);` which is wrong. We have to make a copy.

Comment: Have you got a standard reference for that? My attempts with online compiler seem to suggest `{y, z, x}` is giving `std::tuple{y, z, x}`

Comment: @M.M: [Demo](https://ideone.com/WlEWgd) with `{y, z, x}`. the only deducible `operator=` is the copy assignment from `std::tie`, so a tuple of references.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

1. Introduce temporary variable:

   int temporary = y;
   y = x;
   x = temporary;
2. Or use std::swap like this `std::swap(x, y);` (you might need to import `<algorithm>` or `<utility>`)

Now why you are getting this error? Let's analyze what you are doing here step by step:

1. `x = y;` Give x value of y. So now x is equal to y
2. `y = x;` Give y value of x. But wait, x is now equal to y. So nothing changes.

If you still have trouble understanding what you did wrong I suggest taking a piece of paper and following your own code step by step on paper writing state of program at each step.

And one last thing as advice for the future. Please make you questions clear and properly formatted. For example, it totally don't understand your point with 3 values. Please explain what you mean and probably provide some example and then maybe someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x=4;
    int y=6;

    int temp=x;
    x=y;
    y=temp;
    cout<<x<<y;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=4
y=6

x=y // x=6, y=6

y=x // does nothing
```

Try using another variable:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x=4;
    int y=6;
    int temp=x;
    x=y,y=temp;
    cout<<x<<y;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the comment i will get better in this, i hope.

Answer (score 0):

Without using a third variable you can do swapping two variables like this,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x=4;
    int y=6;

    x = x + y;
    y = x - y;
    x = x - y;
    cout<<"X = "<<x << "\n"
        <<"Y = "<<y;
    return 0;
}
```

So the output will be,

> X = 6
>
> Y = 4

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to swap 2 variables(1 line)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x = 4;
    int y = 6;
    cout << x<< y;
    swap(x,y);
    cout << x << y;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is code to swap 3 variables(1 line)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x = 4;
    int y = 6;
    int z = 8;
    cout << x<< y<<z;
    tie(x, y, z) = make_tuple(y, z, x);
    cout << x << y << z;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are already many answers to this.  Also you define z but do not use it.  Explain how your answer is different from the others?

Comment: I defined variable z when I was tying to swap with 3 variable, I forgot to remove it.MY answer is different because it only involves one line of code.